# Custom MailChimp Form background image in mobile not displaying right

Tags: php, css, wordpress

So I doing some work on this new website called http://tnsac.com/request-free-estimate/ and I form from the widget works great when the width of the page is medium to big, but once it goes below 980px for some reason the background color of the widget area is overlaying the content even though the form should be contained in the DIV.

This is the code for the widget in the sidebar.php file and the CSS for the form. The page that I am talking about is tnsac.com/request-free-estimate/

```
<div id="secondary" class="widget-area col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" role="complementary">
    <?php do_action( 'before_sidebar' ); ?>
    <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) : ?>

        <aside id="search" class="widget widget_search">
            <?php get_search_form(); ?>
        </aside>

        <aside id="archives" class="widget">
            <h1 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Archives', 'blain' ); ?></h1>
            <ul>
                <?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly' ) ); ?>
            </ul>
        </aside>

        <aside id="meta" class="widget">
            <h1 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Meta', 'blain' ); ?></h1>
            <ul>
                <?php wp_register(); ?>
                <li><?php wp_loginout(); ?></li>
                <?php wp_meta(); ?>
            </ul>
        </aside>

    <?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?>
</div><!-- #secondary -->
```

CSS For the Form that has the blue background that I want the form to be.

```
#mc_embed_signup form {display:block; position:relative; text-align:left; padding:10px 0 10px 3%; background-color:#3498db;}
#mc_embed_signup h2 {font-weight:400; color: #fff; padding:0; margin:15px 0; font-size:1.4em;}
#mc_embed_signup input {border:1px solid #999; -webkit-appearance:none;}
#mc_embed_signup input[type=checkbox]{-webkit-appearance:checkbox;}'
#mc_embed_signup input[type=radio]{-webkit-appearance:radio;}
#mc_embed_signup input:focus {border-color:#333;}
#mc_embed_signup .button {clear:both; background-color: #e67e22; border: 0 none; border-radius:4px; color: #FFFFFF; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; font-size:1.5em; font-weight: bold; height: 32px; line-height: 32px; margin: 0 5px 10px 0; padding: 0 22px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: top; white-space: nowrap; width: auto;}
#mc_embed_signup .button:hover {background-color:#f39c12;}
#mc_embed_signup .small-meta {font-size: 11px;}
#mc_embed_signup .nowrap {white-space:nowrap;}

#mc_embed_signup .mc-field-group {clear:left; position:relative; width:96%; padding-bottom:3%; min-height:50px;}
#mc_embed_signup .size1of2 {clear:none; float:left; display:inline-block; width:46%; margin-right:4%;}
#mc_embed_signup .size1of2 {margin-right:2%; /* Fix for IE6 double margins. */}
#mc_embed_signup .mc-field-group label {display:block; margin-bottom:3px; color:#fff;}
#mc_embed_signup .mc-field-group input {display:block; width:100%; padding:8px 0; text-indent:2%;}
#mc_embed_signup .mc-field-group select {display:inline-block; width:99%; padding:5px 0; margin-bottom:2px;}

#mc_embed_signup .datefield, #mc_embed_signup .phonefield-us{padding:5px 0;}
#mc_embed_signup .datefield input, #mc_embed_signup .phonefield-us input{display:inline; width:60px; margin:0 2px; letter-spacing:1px; text-align:center; padding:5px 0 2px 0;}
#mc_embed_signup .phonefield-us .phonearea input, #mc_embed_signup .phonefield-us .phonedetail1 input{width:40px;}
#mc_embed_signup .datefield .monthfield input, #mc_embed_signup .datefield .dayfield input{width:30px;}
#mc_embed_signup .datefield label, #mc_embed_signup .phonefield-us label{display:none;}

#mc_embed_signup .indicates-required {text-align:right; font-size:11px; margin-right:4%;}
#mc_embed_signup .asterisk {color:#c60; font-size:150%;}
#mc_embed_signup .mc-field-group .asterisk {position:absolute; top:25px; right:10px;}        
#mc_embed_signup .clear {clear:both;}

#mc_embed_signup .mc-field-group.input-group ul {margin:0; padding:5px 0; list- style:none;}
#mc_embed_signup .mc-field-group.input-group ul li {display:block; padding:3px 0; margin:0;}
#mc_embed_signup .mc-field-group.input-group label {display:inline;}
#mc_embed_signup .mc-field-group.input-group input {display:inline; width:auto; border:none;}

#mc_embed_signup div#mce-responses {float:left; top:-1.4em; padding:0em .5em 0em .5em; overflow:hidden; width:90%;margin: 0 5%; clear: both;}
#mc_embed_signup div.response {margin:1em 0; padding:1em .5em .5em 0; font-weight:bold; float:left; top:-1.5em; z-index:1; width:80%;}
#mc_embed_signup #mce-error-response {display:none;}
#mc_embed_signup #mce-success-response {color:#529214; display:none;}
#mc_embed_signup label.error {display:block; float:none; width:auto; margin-left:1.05em; text-align:left; padding:.5em 0;}

#mc-embedded-subscribe {clear:both; width:auto; display:block; margin:1em 0 1em 5%;}
#mc_embed_signup #num-subscribers {font-size:1.1em;}
#mc_embed_signup #num-subscribers span {padding:.5em; border:1px solid #ccc; margin- right:.5em; font-weight:bold;}
```

I hope that this makes sense?

Comment: It would appear that you have solved this issue? I can't seem to replicate it. Or is it happening only in some browsers?

Comment: Yes, thank you. It was another plugin that was causing the problem.